# Проблема с иконкой в трее C#

Tags: c#, winforms

имеется проблема с иконкой приложения в трее а именно,иконка в трее появляется и исчезает при этом все это происходит моментально.Вот код на сворачивание

```
        private void laun2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "name";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Cвернут в трей";
            notifyIcon1.Text = "name";

         }

        private void laun2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

            }
            else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
            { notifyIcon1.Visible = false; }
```

При этом если убрать if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) и все что за ним,то создается просто очень много иконок.До сегодняшнего дня все было нормально,я ничего не менял,просто запустил программу.

Comment: Заметил одну особенность,когда я отключаю 3-й таймер,то все работает как надо.Но этот таймер каждые 3 секунды проверяет наличие одного процесса

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил проблему.

Каждые 3 секунды таймер проверяет есть ли процесс. Если процесса нет, то написать об этом. Вот это сообщение об отсутствие процесса обновляло форму и создавало новую иконку.

Я отключил таймер, и включался он только когда это действительно необходимо.

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь давать более структурированые ответы.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/430199)

Comment: Как понять "попросить у автора уточнения" если я автор вопроса,и автор ответа

Comment: Верно, "попросить у автора уточнения" у Вас не получится. Но Вы опубликовали в ответе информация о том, что делает опубликованный код. Эту информацию стоит вносить в вопрос. А в ответе должен быть описан вариант решения вознишей проблемы.

Comment: Я написал что вызывало мою проблему

Comment: Тогда напишите как именно решили проблему. Что-то в стиле:  проблема была в том-то, убрал такой-то кусок кода, добавил то-то, изменил то-то. 
 Так чтобы человек который найдет Ваш ответ мог понять, что ему нужно сделать чтобы побороть ошибку, а не только порадоваться за автора который "Вобщем решил проблему".

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо что указали на ошибку